# Slick update tuple with more than 22 elements

Tags: database, scala, playframework, slick

I'm running a [Scala Play](https://www.playframework.com/) project where Slick is used for the database.

I've now added a new field to the *Books* table in the database and when I try to update an item like I used to do before I get the following error: *tuples may not have more than 22 elements, but 23 given*.

How do I run a update query with more than 22 fields?

```
val q =
  for { book <- Books.filter(_.uuid === book.uuid) } yield (
    book.field1,
    book.field2,
    book.field3,
    book.field4,
    book.field5,
    book.field6,
    book.field7,
    book.field8,
    book.field9,
    book.field10,
    book.field11,
    book.field12,
    book.field13,
    book.field14,
    book.field15,
    book.field16,
    book.field17,
    book.field18,
    book.field19,
    book.field20,
    book.field21,
    book.field22,
    book.field23    
  )
db.run(
  q.update(
    (
      details.field1,
      details.field2,
      details.field3,
      details.field4,
      details.field5,
      details.field6,
      details.field7,
      details.field8,
      details.field9,
      details.field10,
      details.field11,
      details.field12,
      details.field13,
      details.field14,
      details.field15,
      details.field16,
      details.field17,
      details.field18,
      details.field19,
      details.field20,
      details.field21,
      details.field22,
      Timestamp.from(Instant.now)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Having a class with more than 22 fields is usually a bad design symptom

Comment: That I can agree upon, but I'm still interested if there is a way to update a model with more than 22 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from writing your own implementation of a tuple. But as said: It's bad practice. You probably have a lot of fields that should be in other tables.

An example can be found here: (it's old but more or less still the same)

https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Tuple22.scala

But I honestly don't know if it will properly work, because I don't know what other code is being called.

I do like the question about updating more fields, because I'm working on an application that has a lot of datapoints for some elements; but I'll still try to split them.